# Apps can't be minimized/closed when those buttons are on a specific position

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, desktop-apps

Just as the title says, I can't minimize/maximize/close some apps (tested with firefox and discord) because the DE aparently thinks my mouse is on the top bar on the system tray icons (whenever I have anydesk in the system tray, if I right click, I can see the menu as if I clicked on the icon).

I have installed separately gnome (left ubuntu-gnome-desktop) installed and the issue doesn't happen there (it only has the close button for some reason?).

I have purged, removed and then reinstalled ubuntu-gnome-desktop but the issue persists.

I am going to leave a link below with a video explaining my whole issue.

OS: Ubuntu 23.04

(there aren't any updates available through the software updater nor through apt)

Video with demonstration of the issue: https://youtu.be/0sLHDxz4V3w

EDIT: Tested some other apps and Steam doesn't work properly as well. As somebody else described, this issue does not happen on the USB drive, so the clean install might fix it.

EDIT #2: On gnome (not ubuntu-gnome-desktop) I do not have any system tray icons. After installing the extension for gnome called "Tray Icons: Reloaded" by trayIconsReloaded@selfmade.pl the issue came back, so the issue comes from the system tray extension either on gnome and ubuntu-gnome-desktop

EDIT #3: This issue might be caused by anydesk as the hovering displays the name of Anydesk.

Thanks in advance,
Eduardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with Ubuntu 23.04. I updated 22.04 to 22.10 and then to 23.04. I tested, there is no problem when booting from live USB, so I guess that a clean install will fix the issue, but I have lots of apps and customizations...
Still haven't tried anything, waiting for a solution.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Sorry for the deleted edit, this is how to fix:

"sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell"

Then Log out and sign bank in, do not restart.

However an update prompt appears asking for reboot, and after the reboot the issue is back. :(

Final edit: Sorry, the issue is caused by Anydesk icon. I ran:

"systemctl disable anydesk.service"

Rebooted and the issue is gone!

Comment: Great find, thanks.  I had some odd behaviour on my recently Ubuntu 23.10 laptop instance, and wondered if it was the upgrade, but it turned out to be anydesk.